# PC as Bluetooth Headset for iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I am trying to set up my computer (running Windows 8.1) as a headset for answering/making calls for my iPhone 4S. I have connected my iPhone through bluetooth, and can listen to music and create keyboard inputs, but cannot use Handsfree!

[image: iPhone Bluetooth Connection Page]

I have all of the services enabled for the iPhone:

[image: iPhone Services]

I don't understand why my PC cannot act as a bluetooth headset, as Hands-free is selected! I have the latest bluetooth drivers installed for my computer. My guess is that it may be two drivers not working correctly (seen in Device Manager):

[image: Device Manager]

Could these two drivers (MAP MAS-iOS and Wireless iAP) not being installed be the cause of the problem? I have been searching for these drivers online and cannot find them.

Comment: I now understand MAP MAS-iOS is for sending messages, so I guess its not that...

Comment: It could be specific to my manufacturer's drivers: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/319533-bluetooth-hands-free-windows-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that these features are specific to the manufacturers Bluetooth drivers. I was able to find another manufacturers drivers, and they have hands-free as a function:

[image: Working as headset]

Comment: Whose drivers did you find that worked?

Comment: Hi! Can you mention the exact driver you used?